# Which is more important and when: Buying property or collecting promotions?

Tags: fortune-street-wii

*Game: Fortune Street series, specifically the Wii version*

There are cases where you have the choice to buy more property or to take the path that leads to a faster promotion. For example, you could turn left to get the fourth suit, or your could turn right to land on a valuable, unowned shop. Promotions seem like they provide more money than anything else on a consistent basis, but of course having expensive shops provides money in random bursts directly from opponents.

Is one of these choices definitively better than the other? Does this balance change depending on the stage of the game?

Comment: what game is this for